# Vue router lazy loading not working or creating separate chunk files

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to implement some lazy loading on my routes but not being successful. This is how my index.js files on my router folder looks likes

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Login from "../views/Login";
import Register from "../views/Register";
import ResetPw from "../views/ResetPw";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/login",
        name: "login",
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: "/register",
        name: "register",
        component: Register,
    },
    {
        path: "/resetpw",
        name: "resetpw",
        component: ResetPw,
    },
    {
        path: "/member",
        name: "memberlist",
        // component: Memberlist,
        component: () => import('../views/MemberList.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/removed",
        name: "removedlog",
        // component: RemovedLog,
        component: () => import('../views/RemovedLog.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/log",
        name: "pointlog",
        // component: PointLog,
        component: () => import('../views/PointLog.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/:name",
        name: "member",
        // component: Member,
        component: () => import('../views/Member.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/edit/:name",
        name: "edit",
        // component: EditPlayer,
        component: () => import('../views/EditPlayer.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/delete/:name",
        name: "delete",
        // component: DeletePlayer,
        component: () => import('../views/DeletePlayer.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/editremoved/:name",
        name: "editremoved",
        // component: EditRemoved,
        component: () => import('../views/EditRemoved.vue'),
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
        next("/login");
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing, this is how the oficial vue-router documentation says to implement the lazy loading https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html and also how many tutorials explain how to implement lazy loading.

When I do a build, it only creates 1 .js file when it is supposed to build one for each route and using the network tab on firefox, when moving between routes no new route .js file is loaded, I only have an app.js

Comment: @tuhin47,  [this](https://gist.github.com/shayaulman/c85ba05a8d20a3657a79dac7f4222688) is my `package.json` file from a project that I encountered this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @nicholasfc what's the version of vue js ?

Comment: any info on this question? did you finally solve it?

Answer (score -1):

It could be that you're forgetting the `webpackChunkName` comment. To achieve that you need to use named chunks by providing a chunk name using a special comment syntax. Here's an example:

```js
{
   path: '/dashboard',
   name: 'dashboard',
   component: () =>
      import(
         /* webpackChunkName: "Dashboard" */ './components/Dashboard.vue'
      ),
   meta: {
      title: 'Dashboard'
   }
},
```

Comment: Wrong, it also works without it, providing a chunk name is optional.  So this is definitely not the issue.

Comment: Oh, you're right! If you don't define a chunk name webpack assigns a number to it.