# VueJS not creating chunks for lazy loaded route components

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, chunks

My VueJS application is using a router and has a `LoadingPage.vue` component which is being used in the router as follows:

```
{
  path: "/loading",
  name: "loading",
  component: () =>
    import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "loading" */
      /* webpackPrefetch: false */
      /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      "../views/LoadingPage.vue"
    ),
}
```

Upon visiting the `/loading` route, the component is being shown successfuly. However, I'm not seeing a separate chunk when I inspect the files request by the browser.

Here's a screenshot of the `.js` files that are being loaded:
[image: Screenshot of JS files]

I expected a `loading.[hash].js` file there, but it's missing.

What could be causing this problem? I'm using `vue 2.6.14` and `vue-router 3.5.1`

I also haven't touched the `vue.config.js` file, it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: "source-map",
  },
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you creating a production build?

Comment: @StevenSpungin no, my testing was done via `npm run serve`. In the production build situation is the same, I only have two `.js` files: `app.[hash].js` and `chunk-vendors.[hash].js`.

Comment: run `npm run build` and look in the `dist` directory.  and remove all but `webpackChunkName` from your comment directives.

Comment: @StevenSpungin, I only have two .js files: app.[hash].js and chunk-vendors.[hash].js

Comment: Are you referencing the module from anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Which module? `LoadingPage.vue` is only referenced in `index.ts` for my router.

Comment: Did you try to create one more lazy route?  Perhaps if only 1 route, it wont get generated.

Comment: Yes, I actually have a second lazy route, but the problem is still present.

Comment: Which is the default route you load for your app?

Comment: @Michael, did you solve this in the end?

Comment: @ShayaUlman nope.

Comment: @Michael I'm offering now a bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61086044/10679649). You can upvote the question to draw some attention to it.

Comment: @ShayaUlman Thanks! I'll be watching, Hope we'll find a solution :)

Comment: @ShayaUlman I think both of these issues are impossible to solve without knowing what Webpack config is Vue CLI using to build the app. Try running `vue inspect --mode production`

Comment: @MichalLevý, Thanks. which part of the output is relevant to the problem? [here](https://gist.github.com/shayaulman/1184435730428068a4f16adbaea4c0c4) is a gist with the output

Comment: @ShayaUlman Config looks ok (`splitChunks` part is probably most relevant). But your problem is not reproducible. Fresh starter app created with Vue CLI 4.5.17 (newest 4.x release) is using same settings and correctly creates separate async chunks for each lazy route. I see only viable course of action now and that is to try to create minimal reproducible example of the problem and share it (ideally as a git repo). Otherwise it is just guessing game

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as well. I  solved it but deleting extra import statement at the top of the file. Try to make sure you are not importing the same component twice.

My route : [Route in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bme7c.png)

Import statement in index.js: [Import statement in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ry4.png)

Once i deleted all the duplicate component (Account etc) and run build, a separate chunk created : [Admin chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIVyJ.png)

Hope it can solve your problem as well.